# usage of 'never again'

Tags: grammar

Is it mandatory that 'never again' is not separated in a sentence?

Do I have to write "I will never again do anything like that." or may I also put it "I will never do anything like that again."?

If you may separate the two words, is there a rule when to separate them?

Comment: It's true that *never* and *again* often occur consecutively in a sentence, but what makes you think there might be some rule of grammar saying this must **always** be the case?

Answer (score 9):

Whether you write the words *never again* together or at a remove from each is a matter of style not grammar. In my view, writing them together gives the phrase slightly more emphasis, but others may have a different opinion.

There is one circumstance, however, when they most usually stay together, namely at the beginning of a clause, followed by an inversion of subject and verb:

- Never again will I listen to what you say.
- Never again will he speak to me like that.

Fronting the expression in this way gives it even greater emphasis.

Comment: Just to clarify: even though in the one circumstance "never again" usually appears together, it is still grammatically acceptable to space them apart—"Never will I listen again to what you say; never will he speak to me like that again."